# Keras.js encoder unable to encode hdf5 model

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to run keras model on browser. I was following [this](https://intoli.com/blog/keras-weight-transfer/) blog.

I've two model files named `model.hdf5` and `model.json`. I have also downloaded the two python files `encoder.py` and `model_pb2.py` from [github repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcranial/keras-js/master/python/) required to separate weights from other data.  When I run

```
python encoder.py ./model.hdf5
```

I am getting the following error.

```
from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encoder.py", line 120, in <module>
    encoder.serialize()
  File "encoder.py", line 68, in serialize
    self.model.model_config = hdf5_file.attrs['model_config']
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/attrs.py", line 60, in __getitem__
    attr = h5a.open(self._id, self._e(name))
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5a.pyx", line 77, in h5py.h5a.open
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (can't locate attribute: 'model_config')"
```

I've googled and couldnot find any solutions.
Why I'm getting this error? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for solving this problem use KerasJs V0.3([download from here](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js/releases))

this problem discuss and solve in github(https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js/issues/87)